# ng-show only working once

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Basically, i am importing a file and upon success/ fail show a bootstrap panel. I am using ng-show. The panel works only one time. If i try to import a file a second time the panel wont show at all. I think its the way its being closed its not tied to the angular. How can i get the panel to show/hide more than one time?

Here is part of my controller.

```
$scope.importValidatedFile = function(){
    var file = $scope.importFile;
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $scope.loading = true;

    $http.post('rest/importfeed/import/' + $scope.selectedSource.sourceId, fd,{
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }).
    success(function (data) {
        $scope.loading = false;

       $scope.fileSuccess = true;   //here is the panel


        document.getElementById('fileInput').value = "";
        angular.element(document.getElementById('validate'))[0].disabled = true;
        angular.element(document.getElementById('import'))[0].disabled = true;

    }).
    error(function (error) {
        $scope.danger = true;
        document.getElementById('fileInput').value = "";
        angular.element(document.getElementById('validate'))[0].disabled = true;
        angular.element(document.getElementById('import'))[0].disabled = true;
    }).finally(function () {
        $scope.loading = false;
    });

};
```

Here is the panel on the html page.

```
 <div ng-show="fileSuccess">
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-12">
       <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-xs-12 alert alert-success" id="success">

    <button type="button" class="close" data-target="#success" data-dismiss="alert"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
       </button>
      <div class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok success-gliph"></div>
      <div class="success-text"><b>Success!</b></div>
      <p class="record-text">The Record was saved.</p>
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I have a sneaky suspicion its how its being closed and how angular doesn't know about it.

What can i do to get the panel in ng-show to work more than once?

EDIT** I tried adding this to the button.

```
<button ng-click="check();" type="button" class="close" data-target="#success" data-dismiss="alert"> <span ng-click="check();" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
```

and in angular controller

```
 $scope.check = function (){
    alert("in check");
    $scope.fileSuccess = false;
};
```

and it still doesnt work

Comment: try using ng-if instead of ng-show

Comment: Does it work if you add $scope.$apply(); in the end of your $scope.check function? It's not the way it's supposed to be done, but at least you'll now that your problems is angular apply not invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this? reset fileSucess every time you call importValidateFile(), and change ng-show to ng-if in your html

```
$scope.importValidatedFile = function(){
    var file = $scope.importFile;
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.fileSuccess = false;

$http.post('rest/importfeed/import/' + $scope.selectedSource.sourceId, fd,{
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
}).
```

Comment: How does the ng-if look in the html. I have never used it. Thanks

Comment: change  <div ng-show="fileSuccess">
 to <div ng-if="fileSuccess">

Comment: Glad it helped. You can think of ng-if will remove the html elements from the DOM, and recompile the html when it is true again. Ng-show will preserve the html in the DOM and just display it again. Generally in most cases it should work either you use ng-if or ng-show. But since bootstrap does some weird thing to hide the panel, using ng-if serves like a trick to make it recompile again. If you want to, you can do more research or go into the bootstrap source code to see why. But yea, glad it works now and you should look at the difference between ng-if and ng-show

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That helps!